# Jackrabbit query for version labels taking 40 minutes time

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit

I need to track the history of files and need to show history to a user based on the selected node. I am using Apache jackrabbit to get the data for a particular version label. I am using the following query:

```
 SELECT versioned.[jcr:uuid] 
 FROM [nt:frozenNode] AS versioned 
 INNER JOIN [nt:version] AS version 
 ON ISCHILDNODE(versioned,version) INNER JOIN [nt:versionLabels] as node 
 ON node.[20170921114713] = version.[jcr:uuid]
```

But my version DB has 133129 records. Query is taking 35 minutes to execute. Please let me know how can I achieve best performance time.  Anybody having similar requirement and implemented with good performance, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Found that query is taking too much of time because of huge data in forzen node. Also getting GC over limit .

Used API to fetch the data. now time decreased to 90seconds.

TreeTraverser traverse = new TreeTraverser(node, null, TreeTraverser.InclusionPolicy.LEAVES);
        int count = 0;
        for (Node r : traverse) {
          count++;
          Node parent = r.getParent();
          String test = parent.getPath();
          VersionHistory history1 = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().getVersionHistory(test);
          HashSet<String> test1 = printHistory1(history1);
          map.put(test, test1);
        }
```